# Create non-flat Java packages in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to create file foder like this:

[image]

But in Intelij it always show this:

[image]

How can I solve it, pls?

Comment: So you don't want to see the packages collapsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just unselect option in `Project -> (Gear icon ⚙) -> Compact Empty Middle Packages`.

Then select a folder and create next package node.

See on [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3PNk.png) how to turn off flat mode

Answer (score 0):

It flattens **empty** packages. You could either disable the setting as the other answer, or simply put files into those packages.

I think the real problem, though, it that you are actually making a file structure like this

```
core
    item
        lyKhi 
            nguHanh
```

You should right click on "core" when you create a new package.